# javascript/Jquery pop up - only open one pop at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have 3 separate scripts for 3 pop ups, Im sure there is a better way to structure these into one script? I also want to be able to only open one pop up at a time, so if .popup-new is active and i click to open .popup-new-b then .popup-new will automatically close. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".popup-trigger").click(function () {
$(".popup-new").fadeIn(300);

});

$(".popup-new > span, .popup-new").click(function () {
$(".popup-new").fadeOut(300);
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".popup-trigger-b").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-b").fadeIn(300);

});

$(".popup-new-b > span, .popup-new-b").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-b").fadeOut(300);
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".popup-trigger-c").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-c").fadeIn(300);

});

$(".popup-new-c > span, .popup-new-c").click(function () {
$(".popup-new-c").fadeOut(300);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I cannot see your HTML. I have added some with `CSS`. I hope this is what you are looking for. Ofcourse I could've asked clarify but I do not have enough reputation to add comment :(

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.popup').removeClass('popped');
    $('#popup-new'+$(this).attr('class')).addClass('popped');
 });
```

```css
.popup{
   position:fixed;
   width:70%;
   height:70%;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   margin-top:-5%;
   margin-left:-35%;
   background-color:#ccc;
   z-index:100;
   display:none;
}
.popped{
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="popup-new" class="popup">HI I am POPUP NEW</div>
<div id="popup-new-b" class="popup">HI I am POPUP-NEW-B</div>
<div id="popup-new-c" class="popup">HI I am POPUP-NEW-C</div>

<button class="">Pop up New</button>
<button class="-b">Pop up New B</button>
<button class="-c">Pop up New C</button>
```

Comment: Clever use of a common class to hide them all at once.

Comment: Wanted to write less,clean and efficient code :D. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
popups = ['.popup-new','.popup-new-b','.popup-new,-c']

// Pass an additional parameter to popup_click, which is the index of the popup in the array
$('.popup-trigger').click({popup: 0}, popup_click);
$('.popup-trigger-b').click({popup: 1}, popup_click);
$('.popup-trigger-c').click({popup: 2}, popup_click);

function popup_click(event) {
    // Here write the code to open the popup
    // You can access the popup through $(popups[event.data.popup])
    for (var i in popups) {
        if (i != event.data.popup) { // event.data.popup contains the index that we passed
            // Here write the code to close each of the other popups
            // Access them through $(popups [i])
        }
    }
}

$('html').click(function() {
    for (var i in popups) {
        $(popups[i]).hide();
    }
});

$('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e) {
    for (var i in popups) {
        $(popups[i]).hide();
    }
});

$('.popup-new').click(stop_propagation);
$('.popup-new-b').click(stop_propagation);
$('.popup-new-c').click(stop_propagation);

function stop_propagation(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

It is generally a good idea to use arrays or objects whenever you have repetitive code you want to factor.

Note that passing parameters to an event handler this way only works with jQuery; in raw JavaScript you will have to use closures.

You can even simplify both blocks of three lines by using another array and loop (see below).

Also note that as @404UserNotFound wrote, if all of your popups share a common class, you can simplify these lines:

```
for (var i in popups) {
    $(popups[i]).hide();
}
```

And turn them into:

```
$('.yourClassNameHere').hide(); // Will select all the elements of the right class
```

Which leaves you with this compact code:

```
popups = ['.popup-new', '.popup-new-b', '.popup-new,-c']
popup_triggers = ['.popup-trigger', '.popup-trigger-b', '.popup-trigger-c']

// Pass an additional parameter to popup_click, which is the index of the popup in the array
for (i in popup_triggers) {
    $(popup_triggers[i]).click({popup: i}, popup_click);
}

function popup_click(event) {
    // Here write the code to open the popup
    // You can access the popup through $(popups[event.data.popup])
    for (var i in suffixes) {
        if (i != event.data.popup) { // event.data.popup contains the index that we passed
            // Here write the code to close each of the other popups
            // Access them through $(popups [i])
        }
    }
}

$('html').click(function() {
    $('.yourClassNameHere').hide();
});

$('.popup-btn-close').click(function(e) {
    $('.yourClassNameHere').hide();
});

for (i in popups) {
    $(popups[i]).click(stop_propagation);
}

function stop_propagation(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

And finally, if all of your popups and triggers are always named the same way, with a suffix, you could condense it even further (with a few more tricks to save some space):

```js
suffixes = ['', '-b', '-c']

for (let i in suffixes) {
  $('.popup-trigger' + suffixes[i]).click(function(i) {
    return function(e) {
      hideAllPopups();
      $('.popup-new' + suffixes[i]).toggle();
      //e.stopPropagation(); // HERE
    }
  }(i));
}

$('.popup-btn-close').click(hideAllPopups);
//$('html').click(hideAllPopups); // HERE

function hideAllPopups() {
  $('.popup').hide();
}

// Uncomment the two lines marked "HERE" to make the popups disappear whenever you click somewhere in the page (except on the buttons)
```

```css
.popup {
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.popup-btn-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 5px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="box popup-trigger">Trigger popup #1</span>
<span class="box popup-trigger-b">Trigger popup #2</span>
<span class="box popup-trigger-c">Trigger popup #3</span>

<hr/>

<div class="popup-new popup" style="display:none">Popup #1 <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span></div>
<div class="popup-new-b popup" style="display:none">Popup #2 <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span></div>
<div class="popup-new-c popup" style="display:none">Popup #3 <span class="popup-btn-close">X</span></div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing your answers but I am unable to the pop up to fire with the above suggestion. would it help if i shared my html?

Comment: i have added my html

Comment: I am still having difficulty coding opening and closing of the pop up. can you assist?

Comment: I updated my answer, see the snippet at the very bottom.

Comment: On a side note, since you seem to be using Bootstrap, you might look into modals, which wouldn't require the use of any JavaScript at all, just plain CSS and HTML. See an example [here](https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO).

Comment: Many thanks for your in-depth answer and a number of options provided, always good to learn new tricks. i have got this working perfectly but it doesn't seem to fire in safari on MAC or PC, are you aware of a work around?

Comment: From what I can see, there should not be any issue. What version of Safari and jQuery are you using? Can you determine if the event is fired at all (with a `console.log`)?

Comment: there are no errors in the console and the event is fired. Safari 5.1.7 and jQuery 2.1.3. I have created fiddle if that helps https://jsfiddle.net/w5L47Lwb/1/

Comment: I am not sure what I am supposed to see/click on this fiddle, and the display is apparently broken. Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, aka, the shortest page you can write where the bug is present.

Comment: the solution didn't work for me in safari. In the edited question i have a bit of jquery that works across browser but need to compile into one script similar to your solution

Comment: I don't understand your message very well. Is the code in the edited question working, and you only want to factor it, or is it also missing things?

Comment: they are 3 separate scripts that need factoring into one script with the ability to only open one at a time and close if clicked anywhere outside of the box. hope this makes sense,

Comment: Hi pie3636, basically what you previously suggested but using the above scripts as they work across browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant get it to work. i cant implement your solution to the above code I have specified. surely there is a way of combining my 3 scripts into one?